# Sorting lat long coordinates from current location

Tags: java, android

I am trying to sort a list of latitude and longitude coordinates based on their distance from the user's current location. I've tried using comparators, but just can't seem to make it work. I've tried many different ways of implementing the comparator, including using an arraylist, and tried many different tutorials around the web. I was thinking about using a collection and then sorting it, but don't really know how. Am I on the right track with that? My code is below. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great. Thanks so much!

```
package com.example.qdogg.mealmapnb;

 //@Author Quinn Clark 2018
//


/**
 *Sorting based on proximity soon
 */

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.location.Location;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.ListView;

 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Collections;
 import java.util.Comparator;
 import java.util.List;

 public abstract class SleepMap extends MainActivity implements 
OnItemClickListener, LocationProviderSleepMap.LocationProviderListener {
ListView listView;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sleep_map);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sleeplist);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void gotCurrentLocation(Location location) {
    final Location CLSM = new Location("");
    CLSM.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
    CLSM.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());

    Location IFCSM = new Location("");
    IFCSM.setLatitude(51.042580);
    IFCSM.setLongitude(-114.062782);

    Location BGCSM = new Location("");
    BGCSM.setLatitude(51.039370);
    BGCSM.setLongitude(-114.084020);

    float CLSMtoIFCSM = CLSM.distanceTo(IFCSM);
    float CLSMtoBGC = CLSM.distanceTo(BGCSM);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Intent innfromthecold = new Intent(this, ifcactivity.class);
            startActivity(innfromthecold);
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent boysandgirlsclub = new Intent(this, bgcactivity.class);
            startActivity(boysandgirlsclub);
            break;
        default:
            //Nothing

    }
}
}
```

Comment: `gotCurrentLocation()` does some calculations on some **local variables**, so when the method returns those calculated values are lost.  You describe using `ArrayList` and `Compartor`, but none of that code is included in the question.  Please update with the details of what was attempted which is not working.

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo code it should look like this

```
public class DistanceComparator implements Comparator<Location> {
    private Location current;

    public DistanceComparator(Location loc) {
        current = loc;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Location l1, Location l2) {
        int distance1 = calculateDistance(current, l1); // your code to calculate distance
        int distance2 = calculateDistance(current, l2);

        if (distance1 < distance2) return -1;
        if (distance1 == distance2) return 0;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how you are calculating the distance? I'm quite new to this and appreciate the help.

Comment: @QuinnClark exact code depends on your code for `Location` class.

Comment: How might I adapt this for multiple entries? I see that you have `if (distance1 < distance2) return -1; if (distance == distance2) return 0, ;` . Can this work for multiple locations?

Comment: @QuinnClark what do you mean by multiple locations? You add your locations into collection (list, array) and then sort that collection with given comparator. That comparator will order elements in collection according to their distance from a given location

Comment: Sorry, I should probably clarify that. It seemed to me when I was reading your example that that code would only work if I wanted to compare one distance to another. However, I will have many more. I thought that if I just repeated it and then created another comparator to find the closest point out of the others it might work but that seems awfully involved and I'm sure there is a better way.